# How to count how many values in a specific row which are greater than 10 in a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, row

I don't know how to count how many of the values in a specific row which are greater than 10 in a dataframe.

For example below.

```
mtcars 
               mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt ... 
Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.62 ... 
Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.88 ... 
Datsun 710    22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.32 ...
```

The row I want to focus on is the Datsun so say row 3 showing how many values are greater than 10, in which case the answer is 3 because 22.8 (mpg), 108(disp) and 93(hp).

I've tried df[(df[3,]>10),] but doesn't work.

Comment: try `rowSums(mtcars > 10)`

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it in the style you got started with is:

```
length(df[3,][(df[3,])>10])
```

or `sum(df[3,]>10)`

Comment: So if I was to say between 10 and 20 instead of greater than 10 sum(df[3,]>10&<20)?

Comment: You'd need to specify the vector reference again, so `sum(df[3,]>10 & df[3,]<20)`.

Comment: If I was to select specific data for example mazda RX4 hp, would I go about like this?  "df ['Mazda RX4,hp]" ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `table()` function.

**I.  ALL NUMERIC COLUMNS**

For Row 3rd in `mtcars` dataset. Check how many column values in Row 3rd are greater than 10.

**Row 3 values > 10**

```
table(mtcars[3,] > 10)

# FALSE  TRUE 
#     7     4
```

Out of 11 numeric columns, 4 of them have value greater than 10 and 7 of the columns have less than 10.

To know **which are those values in the 3rd row greater than 10**

```
mtcars[3,][which(mtcars[3,] >10)]
#             mpg disp hp  qsec
# Datsun 710 22.8  108 93 18.61
```

Check How many column values in Row 3rd are greater than 10 and less than 20

**Row 3 value > 10 & < 20**

```
table(mtcars[3,] > 10 & mtcars[3,] < 20)

# FALSE  TRUE 
#    10     1
```

To know **which are those values in the 3rd row greater than 10 and less than 20**

```
mtcars[3,][which(mtcars[3,] >10 & mtcars[3,] < 20)]
#             qsec
# Datsun 710 18.61
```

---

**II. ANY FACTOR COLUMN IN DATA**

If any factor or character column or non-numeric in data, the `table( )` will throw **warning message**. But it will give you count for numeric columns which is what we want.

For example, in iris dataset, we have 5th Column as `Species` factor column.

**Glimpse of Iris dataset**

```
head(iris, n = 4)
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
```

**Iris 3rd Row values > 4**

As you see below, count for only 4 columns have come, out of which only one column has value greater than 4. As the 5th column in iris dataset is a factor, it is throwing warning message that we cannot check if Species levels are greater than 4 or not.

```
table(iris[3,] > 4)

# FALSE  TRUE 
#     3     1 

# Warning message:
# In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors
```

**Which column value is greater than 4 in 3rd Row of iris dataset**

```
iris[3,][which(iris[3,] > 4)]
#   Sepal.Length
# 3          4.7

# Warning message:
# In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors
```